# how to check that WiFi or data connection is on but internet accessible or not

Tags: android

I want to check that WiFi or Mobile Data Connection is(able to check) on but able to access internet or not

```
   public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                    = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
        }



  public static boolean isInternetAccessible(Context context) {
        if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
            try {
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://aapapps.com").openConnection());
                urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
                urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500);
                urlc.connect();
                return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Couldn't check internet connection", e);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Internet not available!");
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: your question confused me. Are you want to check the Internet is available or not ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect whether there is an Internet connection available on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-android)

Comment: I want to check that internet is accessible or not if mobile or data connection is on

Answer (score 3):

try its working code

```
public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  if (connectivity != null) 
  {
      NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
      if (info != null) 
          for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
              if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
              {
                  return true;
              }

  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: How it will answer the above question? If wifi is connected but there is no internet available! same in case of data.

Answer (score 0):

check the following code and you have to add internet access permission in your manifest file. If isInternetConnectionAvailable() return true then your device can access internet otherwise it is not connect to internet.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

public boolean isInternetConnectionAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();//active network information
        if (networkInfo != null) {
            return networkInfo.isConnected();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

if you require all network information, then use following code.

```
NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking if the device is connected via WiFi or Mobile Data, why not just ping Google or any other web app which has maximum chances for being consistently available?

If you get a valid response, there is access to internet.